# SignaR Console Unable to Start() HubConnection Localhost

Tags: signalr

I Have created an application one is web and another is console.
On web all the users are connected to a hub.
On console application I connect to the web and hub and start message. It works fine when I opened my application in 1 web browser.

In my console.

```
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://192.168.1.160:1000/");
var chat = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");

hubConnection.Start().Wait();
chat.Invoke("NotifyAllClients", "Hello").Wait();
```

It works very well. I opened the web application (http://192.168.1.160:1000/) use the javascript client libraries for SignalR and connect successfully.

Then run the console, it shows the message from console to web. Perfect.

Not I face issue with another case.

When I open the same application in multiple browser

Console will not working. it hung up at line

```
hubConnection.Start().Wait(); // Console hang there...
```

How I send the message to all of the users? Any solution.

Problem 2
When I run the console and refresh the web application. Browser not load the web page. Where is the problem.

Comment: How are you starting off the hub, from with an IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: I cannot reproduce that behaviour, what are you expecting to see? Is it that you're not seeing the messages on the console client? I can open up the JS client in multiple browsers and fire up the console client multiple times without problems.

Problem 2: If you've fired up your console, that means you've sent the message *Hello* and (depending on your hub implementation) the hub has broadcasted the message. Now if you refresh your web page, it cannot know about this message unless you persist the messages within the hub. If you do, you could re-sent the messages upon connection of the client (which is what happens when you refresh your browser client).

Comment: Could you please share a demo source of that.

Comment: What demo source? Persisting the messages?

Comment: Yes, with console and web